# Why doesn't Laureline use her suit's "Juggernaut power"?

Tags: plot-explanation, valerian-city-of-a-thousand-planets

From the trailer and the movie, it is clear that Valerian's armor has a "Juggernaut mode" that enables him to run through walls.

[image: Valerian running through walls]

However, later on when Laureline

> is abducted by the Boulan-Bathor to serve their emperor... *as* food,

why doesn't she use the "Juggernaut mode" to escape captive when she clearly has her armor on with power?

[image: Laureline in cage]

[image: Laureline trying to communicate]

Answer (score 3):

To avoid, as she says, a "diplomatic incident". You can smash your own stuff; not somebody else's. She had not exhausted every means of diplomacy yet, including yelling. Nor did seem to feel that she was ever in eminent danger while still wearing her suit.

Comment: Also, I'd assume Juggernaut mode requires momentum to be effective, which cannot be achieved inside the cage. And once out of the cage, diplomacy can resume.

Comment: Ironically, if she had broken a wall or two, she could have saved the life of a (relatively) innocent emperor and his guards.